# Cannot rotate my image around it's center in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to rotate an image around it's center. here is the code:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0);
    glRotatef(10, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, img);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0);
    glVertex2i(x+width, y);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1);
    glVertex2i(x+width, y+height);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1);
    glVertex2i(x, y + height);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
```

I read everywhere to translate my image to the center of rotation then rotate and translate it back.
But when i tried doing it step by step I found out that when I translate and then rotate it moves the center of rotation along with the image, so it rotates around a point that is offscreen on the same distance from the image as the initial point of rotation from the initial image before translation.
Can anyone tell me why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: I think you should translate the center, not the upper-left corner to the (0,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix-Operations and thus glTranslatef/glRotatef are applied in reversed order. So when your rotation center is c=(x,y), you have to translate along -c first, then rotate and then translate along c.

In your case, you have to exchange the two translate lines to the following:

```
glTranslatef(x, y, 0); //Translate back
glRotatef(10, 0, 0, 1); //Rotate
glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0); //Translate first along -c
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Didn't know it was applied in reverse order.

Comment: They're technically applied in the order written, but it has to do with post-multiplying column-major matrices and the non-commutative nature of matrix multiplication. This is the same reason you generally have to write `projection * view * model * vtx` in a GLSL shader, if you had row-major matrices instead you could write: `vtx * model * view * projection` and get the same results.